# Rotate the first argument to a function to become nth

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

Given a function with at least `n` arguments, I want to rotate the first argument so that it becomes the `n`th argument. For example (in untyped lambda calculus):

```
r(λa. a)                   = λa. a
r(λa. λb. a b)             = λb. λa. a b
r(λa. λb. λc. a b c)       = λb. λc. λa. a b c
r(λa. λb. λc. λd. a b c d) = λb. λc. λd. λa. a b c d
```

And so on.

Can you write `r` in a generic way? What if you know that `n >= 2`?

Here's the problem stated in Scala:

```
trait E
case class Lam(i: E => E) extends E
case class Lit(i: Int) extends E
case class Ap(e: E, e: E) extends E
```

The rotation should take `Lam(a => Lam(b => Lam(c => Ap(Ap(a, b), c))))` and return `Lam(b => Lam(c => Lam(a => Ap(Ap(a, b), c))))`, for example.

Comment: Can we use zygohistomorphic prepromorphisms?

Comment: @alvivi: Damn you! Now I'm way too curious about those zygo-thingies to go to sleep without learning about them.

Comment: @alvivi -- thought you'd like to know: my spell-checker suggested *symplesiomorphic pleomorphism* for *zygohistomorphic prepromorphisms*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, thanks to everyone who provided an answer. Here is the solution I ended up going with. Taking advantage of the fact that I know `n`:

```
rot :: Int -> [Expr] -> Expr
rot 0 xs = Lam $ \x -> foldl App x (reverse xs)
rot n xs = Lam $ \x -> rot (n - 1) (x : xs)

rot1 n = rot n []
```

I don't think this can be solved without giving `n`, since in the lambda calculus, a term's arity can depend on its argument. I.e. there is no definite "last" argument. Changed the question accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

The trick is to tag the "final" value of the functions involved, since to normal haskell, both `a -> b` and `a -> (b->c)` are just functions of a single variable.
If we do that, though, we can do this.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies,FlexibleInstances,FlexibleContexts #-}
module Rotate where

data Result a = Result a

class Rotate f where
  type After f
  rotate :: f -> After f

instance Rotate (a -> Result b) where
  type After (a -> Result b) = a -> Result b
  rotate = id

instance Rotate (a -> c) => Rotate (a -> b -> c) where
  type After (a -> b -> c) = b -> After (a -> c)
  rotate = (rotate .) . flip
```

Then, to see it in action:

```
f0 :: Result a
f0 = Result undefined

f1 :: Int -> Result a
f1 = const f0

f2 :: Char -> Int -> Result a
f2 = const f1

f3 :: Float -> Char -> Int -> Result a
f3 = const f2

f1' :: Int -> Result a
f1' = rotate f1

f2' :: Int -> Char -> Result a
f2' = rotate f2

f3' :: Char -> Int -> Float -> Result a
f3' = rotate f3
```

Answer (score 5):

It's probably impossible without violating the ‘legitimacy’ of HOAS, in the sense that the `E => E` must be used not just for binding in the object language, but for computation in the meta language. That said, here's a solution in Haskell. It abuses a `Literal` node to drop in a unique ID for later substitution. Enjoy!

```
import Control.Monad.State

-- HOAS representation
data Expr = Lam (Expr -> Expr)
          | App Expr Expr
          | Lit Integer

-- Rotate transformation
rot :: Expr -> Expr
rot e = case e of
  Lam f -> descend uniqueID (f (Lit uniqueID))
  _ -> e
  where uniqueID = 1 + maxLit e

descend :: Integer -> Expr -> Expr
descend i (Lam f) = Lam $ descend i . f
descend i e = Lam $ \a -> replace i a e

replace :: Integer -> Expr -> Expr -> Expr
replace i e (Lam f) = Lam $ replace i e . f
replace i e (App e1 e2) = App (replace i e e1) (replace i e e2)
replace i e (Lit j)
  | i == j = e
  | otherwise = Lit j

maxLit :: Expr -> Integer
maxLit e = execState (maxLit' e) (-2)
  where maxLit' (Lam f) = maxLit' (f (Lit 0))
        maxLit' (App e1 e2) = maxLit' e1 >> maxLit' e2
        maxLit' (Lit i) = get >>= \k -> when (i > k) (put i)

-- Output
toStr :: Integer -> Expr -> State Integer String
toStr k e = toStr' e
  where toStr' (Lit i)
          | i >= k = return $ 'x':show i -- variable
          | otherwise = return $ show i  -- literal
        toStr' (App e1 e2) = do
          s1 <- toStr' e1
          s2 <- toStr' e2
          return $ "(" ++ s1 ++ " " ++ s2 ++ ")"
        toStr' (Lam f) = do
          i <- get
          modify (+ 1)
          s <- toStr' (f (Lit i))
          return $ "\\x" ++ show i ++ " " ++ s

instance Show Expr where
  show e = evalState (toStr m e) m
    where m = 2 + maxLit e

-- Examples
ex2, ex3, ex4 :: Expr

ex2 = Lam(\a -> Lam(\b -> App a (App b (Lit 3))))
ex3 = Lam(\a -> Lam(\b -> Lam(\c -> App a (App b c))))
ex4 = Lam(\a -> Lam(\b -> Lam(\c -> Lam(\d -> App (App a b) (App c d)))))

check :: Expr -> IO ()
check e = putStrLn(show e ++ " ===> \n" ++ show (rot e) ++ "\n")

main = check ex2 >> check ex3 >> check ex4
```

with the following result:

```
\x5 \x6 (x5 (x6 3)) ===> 
\x5 \x6 (x6 (x5 3))

\x2 \x3 \x4 (x2 (x3 x4)) ===> 
\x2 \x3 \x4 (x4 (x2 x3))

\x2 \x3 \x4 \x5 ((x2 x3) (x4 x5)) ===> 
\x2 \x3 \x4 \x5 ((x5 x2) (x3 x4))
```

(Don't be fooled by the similar-looking variable names. This is the rotation you seek, modulo alpha-conversion.)

Comment: Hm, now I'm thinking you probably meant `r` to be an untyped lambda calculus term, not a meta language function…?

Comment: One question though. If I have `k = \a \b (a)` and `i = \x (x)`, then `i k = \a \b (a)`. Does this solution make `i k a b` == `(rot i) a b k`? I don't think it does because `rot i` == `i`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I'm posting another answer. And it still might not be exactly what you're looking for. But I think it might be of use nonetheless. It's in Haskell.

```
data LExpr = Lambda Char LExpr
           | Atom Char
           | App LExpr LExpr

instance Show LExpr where
    show (Atom c) = [c]
    show (App l r) = "(" ++ show l ++ " " ++ show r ++ ")"
    show (Lambda c expr) = "(λ" ++ [c] ++ ". " ++ show expr ++ ")"
```

So here I cooked up a basic algebraic data type for expressing lambda calculus. I added a simple, but effective, custom Show instance.

```
ghci> App (Lambda 'a' (Atom 'a')) (Atom 'b')
((λa. a) b)
```

For fun, I threw in a simple `reduce` method, with helper `replace`. Warning: not carefully thought out or tested. Do not use for industrial purposes. Cannot handle certain nasty expressions. :P

```
reduce (App (Lambda c target) expr) = reduce $ replace c (reduce expr) target
reduce v = v

replace c expr av@(Atom v)
    | v == c    = expr
    | otherwise = av
replace c expr ap@(App l r)
                = App (replace c expr l) (replace c expr r)
replace c expr lv@(Lambda v e)
    | v == c    = lv
    | otherwise = (Lambda v (replace c expr e))
```

It seems to work, though that's really just me getting sidetracked. (`it` in ghci refers to the last value evaluated at the prompt)

```
ghci> reduce it
b
```

So now for the fun part, `rotate`. So I figure I can just peel off the first layer, and if it's a Lambda, great, I'll save the identifier and keep drilling down until I hit a non-Lambda. Then I'll just put the Lambda and identifier right back in at the "last" spot. If it wasn't a Lambda in the first place, then do nothing.

```
rotate (Lambda c e) = drill e
    where drill (Lambda c' e') = Lambda c' (drill e') -- keep drilling
          drill e' = Lambda c e'       -- hit a non-Lambda, put c back
rotate e = e
```

Forgive the unimaginative variable names. Sending this through ghci shows good signs:

```
ghci> Lambda 'a' (Atom 'a')
(λa. a)
ghci> rotate it
(λa. a)
ghci> Lambda 'a' (Lambda 'b' (App (Atom 'a') (Atom 'b')))
(λa. (λb. (a b)))
ghci> rotate it
(λb. (λa. (a b)))
ghci> Lambda 'a' (Lambda 'b' (Lambda 'c' (App (App (Atom 'a') (Atom 'b')) (Atom 'c'))))
(λa. (λb. (λc. ((a b) c))))
ghci> rotate it
(λb. (λc. (λa. ((a b) c))))
```

Comment: So yeah, don't try reducing `((λx. x x) (λx. x x))` with my implementation of `reduce` ;)

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it with template haskell would be like this:

With these two functions:

```
import Language.Haskell.TH

rotateFunc   :: Int -> Exp
rotateFunc n = LamE (map VarP vars) $ foldl1 AppE $ map VarE $ (f:vs) ++ [v]
    where vars@(f:v:vs) = map (\i -> mkName $ "x" ++ (show i)) [1..n]

getNumOfParams :: Info -> Int
getNumOfParams (VarI _ (ForallT xs _ _) _ _) = length xs + 1
```

Then for a function `myF` with a variable number of parameters you could rotate them this way:

```
$(return $ rotateFunc $ read $(stringE . show =<< (reify 'myF >>= return . getNumOfParams))) myF
```

There most certainly are neater ways of doing this with TH, I am very new to it.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you could use the techniques described int the paper [An n-ary zipWith in Haskell](http://www.brics.dk/RS/98/38/BRICS-RS-98-38.pdf) for this.

Answer (score -1):

> Can you write `r` in a generic way?
>   What if you know `n`?

**Haskell**

Not in plain vanilla Haskell. You'd have to use some deep templating magic that someone else (much wiser than I) will probably post.

In plain Haskell, let's try writing a class.

```
class Rotatable a where
    rotate :: a -> ???
```

What on earth is the type for rotate? If you can't write its type signature, then you probably need templates to program at the level of generality you are looking for (in Haskell, anyways).

It's easy enough to translate the idea into Haskell functions, though.

```
r1 f = \a -> f a
r2 f = \b -> \a -> f a b
r3 f = \b -> \c -> \a -> f a b c
```

etc.

---

**Lisp(s)**

Some Lispy languages have the [`apply` function (linked: r5rs)](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-9.html?q=apply#%_idx_578), which takes a function and a list, and applies the elements of the list as arguments to the function. I imagine in that case it wouldn't be so hard to just un-rotate the list and send it on its way. I again defer to the gurus for deeper answers.

Comment: Well, the idea is that you would have an untyped lambda calculus embedded in Haskell using higher-order abstract syntax.

Comment: @Apocalisp huh? Are you trying to write this function for Haskell/Scheme or are you trying to write an interpreter for lambda calculus in one of these languages? (I assumed the former) Or are you looking for a solution purely in lambda calculus?

Comment: You could clearly write the type of rotate if you used multiparam type classes and functional dependencies/type families. It would simply be a -> b for suitable a and b :-)